# How to Customise Open source aar code files?

Tags: android, customization, exoplayer, aar, exoplayer2.x

**Tehnology** : Android

**AAR which I need to customize :** Exoplayer2

**What I did :** included the aar dependency in build.gradle, and the files in which I want to customize, took them out from the source code, and put them into exact same folder structure as their AAR, and made required changes in those files.

**Where I stuck :** when I run debug build, then it worked fine but when I tried to make release build it give me below error.

```
(Can't read [com] (Can't read [google] (Can't read [android] (Can't read [exoplayer2] (Can't read [ext] (Can't read [ima] (Can't read [ImaAdsLoader$Builder.class] (Duplicate jar entry [com/google/android/exoplayer2/ext/ima/ImaAdsLoader$Builder.class])))))))))
```

**Below is my debug and release build configuration :**

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '../proguard-rules.txt'
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '../proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
```

**What I tried to resolve this :**
As I took a complete single folder from that particular exoplayer module source, let's say **xyz** So I tried to exclude this folder from the aar dependecy but unable to do so.

Further I am assuming that including the complete source of that module instead of including that aar then issue would be resolved, but I am concerned with gradle dependecies of that module, should I include that too in my build.gradle manually ?

Please let me know the best way to achieve this !!

Comment: When I understood right, you want to customize `Exoplayer2` ?

Comment: right. For my use case I want to customise in exoplayer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize `Exoplayer2`

## A: New own aar

You should fork the repository, make your changes as new commit and build + publish to an maven repo.

## B: Include as code

Or remove the aar dependency, add forked `Exoplayer2` repo as git submodule to your repo. Make your changes and commit to fork and update pointer to submodule in your main repos

## Example

You can look at a running example https://github.com/hannesa2/cwac-saferoom?organization=hannesa2&organization=hannesa2
Here I did exactly option #1 and published changed lib to https://jitpack.io/#hannesa2/cwac-saferoom Here you can see, how to include your new library